# Idiomatic way to avoid variable shadowing in Nim

Tags: naming-conventions, nim-lang

Suppose that I want to define a variable called `sum`, but the name collides with some predefined function. In Python, I would write something like `_sum` or `sum_` to refer to the local variable. However, using underscore in Nim leads to an invalid token error. Is there an accepted naming convention to deal with such cases?

Comment: Isn't it a coincidence that `sum_` gives an error *Error: invalid token: trailing underscore* (I'm looking at your handle) :).

Answer (score 2):

Change both to more descriptive names like `sumProducts`, `sumHorses`.

Answer (score 0):

You are free a use a wide variety of characters, even unicode if you want. So below works:

```nim
proc sum(): int =
  var ∑ = 42 # using ∑ as variable identifier
  return ∑
echo sum() # -> 42
```

---

But **def-** has the right answer: Make the identifiers more descriptive.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not exactly what I am looking for. Some languages have idiomatic ways to distinguish between otherwise identical identifiers. In Haskell one can append a single quotation mark, in Python an underscore. I was wondering if a similar convention existed for Nim.